# Setting number of columns dynamically

Tags: php, html, html-table, bootstrap-4

I'm trying the following:

I need to create a table to store information.

The problem I have is that I need to set the number of columns depending of an array length: 2 columns are always the same (first and last) and between them a variable number of columns.

To calculate the length of each column I used the following rules (I'm testing yet, first and last column takes the remainder of the division between 12):

```
$numberOfColumns = sizeof($hbwellMarginsDataFillers[0]['payMethods'])+2;
$remainder = 12%$numberOfColumns;
$quotient = intdiv(12/$numberOfColumns, 1);

$widthReferralCodeColumn = '';
$widthActionsColumn = '';
$payMethodsColumnsWidth = $quotient;

if($remainder > 0){
    //if remainder is pair
    if($remainder%2 === 0){
        $widthReferralCodeColumn = $quotient + ($remainder/2);
        $widthActionsColumn      = $quotient + ($remainder/2);
    }else{
        $widthReferralCodeColumn = intdiv($remainder/2);
        $widthActionsColumn = $widthReferralCodeColumn + $remainder%2;
    }
}
```

Then to create the header:

```
<div class="row box-table">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel-heading bold panel-title">
                <div class="col-xs-<?= $widthReferralCodeColumn ?> text-center">
                    <span>Código de Referrido</span>
                </div>
                <?php foreach ($hbwellMarginsDataFillers[0]['payMethods'] as $key => $value): ?>
                <div class="col-xs-<?= $payMethodsColumnsWidth ?> text-center">
                    <span><?= $key ?></span>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                <div class="col-xs-<?php $widthActionsColumn ?> text-center">
                    <span>Acciones</span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The result is columns one over other because of the column name.

When I try using  I have it properly distributed, but I need to do it as shown in the code below...is there any way to set columns width dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Check using this :

```
            <?php
            //Columns must be a factor of 12 (1,2,3,4,6,12)
            $numOfCols = 4;
            $rowCount = 0;
            $bootstrapColWidth = 12 / $numOfCols;
            ?>
            <div class="row">
            <?php
            foreach ($rows as $row){
            ?>  
                    <div class="col-md-<?php echo $bootstrapColWidth; ?>">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="user_file/<?php echo $row->foto; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php
                $rowCount++;
                if($rowCount % $numOfCols == 0) echo '</div><div class="row">';
            }
            ?>
            </div>
```